# Drop-down filter is not working as it should

Tags: php, wordpress, filter

My code:

```
<?php
    function filter_profiles_by_country()
    {
        $url = get_site_url();
        if ( $terms = get_terms( array('taxonomy' => 'country','orderby' => 'name') ) )
        {
            // if categories exist, display the dropdown
            echo '<select name="categoryfilter" onchange="if (this.value) window.location.href=this.value">';
            echo '    <option value="'.$url.'/profiles">All Profiles...</option>';
            foreach ( $terms as $term )
            {
                // ID of the category as an option value
                echo '    <option value="'.$url ."/country/". $term->name . '">' . $term->name . '</option>'; 
            }
            echo '</select>';
        }
    }
?>
```

When I click on All Profiles, it should take me to /profiles/ page. But it is not working.

Comment: A `<select>` must be contained inside a `<form>`.  The `<form>` defines which page will process the selection.  In that page you can setup a redirection to another page.  See https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_elements.asp.  If you want the page to react without having to submit the `<form>`, you could setup a Javascript event.  Right now, nothing in your code does anything to redirect.

Comment: @Nic3500 a `<select>` doesn't need to be inside a form to work, the OP is using inline javascript to trigger the event, and this is working for them. The problem is that its not going to the correct location (I think!). But the HTML & js is valid.

Comment: ExTex, when you say its "not working", that doesn't give is anythign to go on, so what exactly do you mean? e.g. do you get an error message, a blank screen, unexpected behaviour? The code you have given us works exactly as indended, so if we don't know what the problem is we can't help :)

Comment: Hi @FluffyKitten, When I click on All Profiles, it should take me to /profiles/ page. But it doesn't work. Other things like Taxonomy and the terms will work. Sorry, I am not from Computer Science background. Please correct me wherever I am wrong. TIA

Comment: ExTex,  I've put your code into one of my WP test sites and it works properly for me. When you say "doesn't work" what do you mean? Do you get an error message? Does it go to the wrong page? If so what page does it go to?

Comment: @FluffyKitten: thanks.  In the context of "pure HTML", without Javascript I do not see what a select would accomplish if now withing a form.  I will research this further.

Comment: @Nic3500 Yes, a select without a form or javascript doesn't accomplish much, but the OP has inline javascript for the select to change the page: `<select name="categoryfilter" onchange="if (this.value) window.location.href=this.value">'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   <?php 

function filter_profiles_by_country(){
        $url = get_site_url();
        global $wp;
    $current_url = home_url(add_query_arg(array(), $wp->request));
    
    if( $terms = get_terms( array(
        'taxonomy' => 'country',
        'orderby' => 'name'
    ) ) ) : 
        // if categories exist, display the dropdown
        echo '<select name="categoryfilter" onchange="if (this.value) window.location.href=this.value"><option value="'.$url.'/profiles/">All Profiles...</option>';
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) :
            $loadedItem = $url."/country/".$term->name;
            $selectedItem = ($current_url == $loadedItem)? "selected": "";
            echo '<option '.$selectedItem.' value="'.$url ."/country/". $term->name . '">' . $term->name . '</option>'; // ID of the category as an option value
        endforeach;
        echo '</select>';
    endif;
    }
?>
```

Try this.